# Yoga Sutra by Jaimini?

Tags: yoga

I have heard that there are treatises on Yoga from Rishis other than Patanjali and one of them is from Rishi Jaimini. Is this true? What are the other Yoga treatises available today and is there any translations of the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. Jaimini does not have a work on yoga but on astrology (see for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaimini_Sutras). There are many texts on yoga and well known are Shiva Samhita, Hatha Yoga Pradipika for example, regarding Hatha Yoga. Both of them have been translated in english.

Comment: Which text is the basis for Hatha Yoga Pradipika?

Comment: You can read about 'Hatha Yoga Pradipika' on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatha_Yoga_Pradipika . Despite those 3 texts are dated more recent than 'Yoga Sutra', 'Shiva Samhita', 'Gheranda Samhita' and 'Hatha Yoga Pradipika' are seen as most well known base texts for Hatha Yoga. As a note, in Vasu's edition of 'Gheranda Samhita' the passage describing Varjoli (translated as Vajroni) Mudra is different than description given in other texts.

Comment: Keep in mind one of the oldest text describing different Yoga Mudra is "Dhyanabindu Upanishad" included in Yajur Veda (Krishnapaksha Yajurveda) and after reading the transliterated Sanskrit version I indeed think this Upanishad to be one good source for later 'Hatha Yoga Pradipika' (see  http://muktalib5.org/DL_CATALOG/DL_CATALOG_USER_INTERFACE/dl_user_interface_create_velthuis_text.php?hk_file_url=..%2FTEXTS%2FETEXTS%2FdhyaanabinduupanisatHK.txt&miri_catalog_number=M00106 ) if you know Sanskrit.

Comment: This Dhyana Bindu Upanishad has been translated in many languages (english, french, etc). See https://ia601406.us.archive.org/35/items/thirtyminorupani00naraiala/thirtyminorupani00naraiala.pdf